# How to Implement DbContextOptionsBuilder in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0

I am new to ASP.Net Core and I am trying to implement ASP.NET Core DI.

I configured like below in ConfigureServices Method in Startup.cs

```
services.AddScoped<DbContext, AutomationDbContext>();
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
services.AddTransient<IUserService, UserService>();
```

In UserService Constructor, I am trying to use DI. I think below is NOT the right way to implement this.

```
public UserService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, AutomationDbContext automationDbContext, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this.configuration = configuration;
        this.optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<AutomationDbContext>();
        var connectionString = this.configuration.GetConnectionString("Automation");
        this.optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        this.automationDbContext = new AutomationDbContext(this.optionsBuilder.Options);
        this.httpContext = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
    }
```

I don't like building optionsbuilder in constructor and get connectionstring. 
What would be the better place to build these optionsBuilder and pass in constructor.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `services.AddDbContext<TContext>` instead:

```
services.AddDbContext<AutomationDbContext>(o =>
    o.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Automation")));
```

Then, just inject your context:

```
public UserService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, AutomationDbContext automationDbContext)
```

As for `IHttpContextAccessor`, you should simply use:

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

However, I would encourage you to *strongly* consider whether you actually need this in your service or not. If you need something like the current user's id, that should be passed into the method that needs it, not retrieved from within your service.

**UPDATE**

Since it was brought up, let me elucidate the reasons why adding your context in the way you currently are is incorrect, since it will shed a little light on how DI works in general.

First, you're binding `DbContext` directly to `AutomationDbContext`, which means you can then only use that one context. Maybe you don't need more than one context... now. That could change later. Second, when you register a service in that way, you can only inject the abstract type, i.e. `DbContext` here. The service registration literally means "when you see `DbContext`, inject an instance of `AutomationDbContext`". If you try to inject `AutomationDbContext` directly, as you're currently doing in your controller, that will actually throw an exception because that type is not actually registered as service: `DbContext` is. Third, `AddScoped` provides no real ability to configure the context, which is of course the part your were missing. There's ways to work around this such as using the factory overload of `AddScoped` or defining `OnConfiguring` on your context, but both of those are substandard to just using the right method in the first place: `AddDbContext<TContext>`

For what it's worth, there's also somewhat of a fourth reason, in that you can opt to use `AddDbContextPool<TContext>` instead of `AddDbContext<TContext>`, for connection pooling. There's no other way to set that up, so if you did want/need connection pooling, you'll never get there with `AddScoped`.

Comment: Thank you! I added HttpContextAccessor like this   services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

Comment: I know. That's technically fine, but the standard is to use `services.AddHttpContextAccesor`. That noticeably divorces the implementation from the interface and abstracts the lifetime. If the ASP.NET Core team changes the default implementation to a different type or decides to use a different lifetime, then you're covered with `AddHttpContextAccessor`, whereas the code you have now would start to fail. While it's admittedly not very likely either of those will change, it's always better to go as abstract as possible.

Comment: so, are you saying this is also not a standard services.AddScoped<DbContext, AutomationDbContext>();

Comment: Well, yes and no. That's different in that adding the context in that way is just wrong and won't work at all, whereas there's just a simpler and better way with `IHttpContextAccessor`.